# A side of one square equals a diagonal of a second square. Find the ratio of the area of the larger square to that of the smaller square.

Tags: geometry

> A side of one square equals a diagonal of a second square. Find the ratio of the area of the larger square to that of the smaller square.

Thanks.

This isn't homework, I'm triying to learn geometry for myself and get struggled in this part. Sorry if I didn't said this before.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! ... The community prefers/expects a question to include something of what the asker knows about the problem. (*What have you tried? Where did you get stuck?* etc) This helps answerers tailor their responses to best serve you, without wasting time (theirs or yours) explaining things you already understand or using techniques beyond your skill level. (It also helps convince people that you aren't simply trying to get them to do your homework for you. An isolated problem statement with no evidence of personal effort makes a poor impression, attracting down- and close-votes.)

Comment: A common strategy will just be to decide the size of one of the lengths. Say that the side of the first square is $1$. You can then find the area of each square and find the ratio explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

$\tiny\text{( Proof without words, but MSE wants 30 characters... )}$

[image]

Comment: I've made a similar picture myself, too, but too late... :)

Comment: @CiaPan Just for fun, this is going to the big bucket of closed questions, anyway ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Let the side of one square be $x$ units.

$\Rightarrow$ Side of second square=$x\sqrt2$

Area of first square=$x^2$ sq. units

Area of second square=$(x\sqrt2)^2=2x^2$ sq. units

$\Rightarrow$ Ratio of area of larger square to smaller square=$\frac{2x^2}{x^2}=2$